# nginx : HTTP/2 switch to HTTP/1.1 (testing)

Tags: nginx, http-2

For testing purpose, I have been trying to switch my nginx server back to HTTP/1.1. I've been using HTTP/2 since it was first available (release 1.9.5).

According to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html) and this [release note](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-9-5/), HTTP/2 is enabled simply by setting `http2` is the `listen` directive in my `server`block.

However, it appears that removing "http2" doesn't force the server to use HTTP again.

Thoughts ?

*Environment: Debian 8.5, nginx 1.11.1 compiled with LibreSSL 2.3.8*

Thank you.

Comment: Check ALL listen directives in all server blocks and remove http2 from all of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on Alexey Ten comment above (thank you !), I confirm that nginx requires to have *no* server(s) running HTTP/2 to get back to HTTP/1.1 (default).

In other words, setting up the directive `http2` in one server will enable it for all of them.